# stopping a `const` member from being edited under another alias

Tags: c++, constants, alias, abstract, member

I have a class with an `const` abstract member. Since it is abstract, the object must reside in a higher scope. However, it may be edited in this higher scope. I have made this MWE, and added comments explaining what I am trying to achieve (.i.e. I know this does NOT achieve what I want).

Besides commenting the hell out of it, what can be done to stop the user from editing the object. Preferably, an idiot proof method (optimally, compile error)

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    private:
        const int * p_abstract_const;   
        //int my application this is a pointer to abstract object
    public:
        Foo(const int * p_new_concrete_const)
        {
            p_abstract_const  = p_new_concrete_const;
        }

        void printX()
        {
            std::cout << *p_abstract_const << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int concrete_nonconst = 666;
    Foo foo(&concrete_nonconst);    // I want this NOT to compile
  //const int concrete_const(1);
  //Foo foo(&concrete_const);       // only this should compile 
    foo.printX();
    concrete_nonconst=999;          // so that this will NOT be possible
    foo.printX();

}
```

Comment: Don't take a reference, make a copy. That way, the calling code will not have access to the original object.

Comment: @MatsPetersson How can I do that when the member is abstract?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by abstract?the member is a native type (int) not a class

Comment: Well, then let your class CREATE it, based on a factory function. Again, the goal is "do not provide the client code a chance to mess up". The alternative solution, which most system developers follow is "If programmers using this are idiots, let them shoot themselves in the foot as much as the like".

Comment: This is not possible. Even if it was, any user could simply cast it to const (a perfectly valid cast) while calling the function. Just trust the user not to be a complete idiot and document it.

Comment: @Heisenbug only for the sake of the MWE. In my application it is not

Comment: You have `int concrete_nonconst = 666;` and then `concrete_nonconst=999; // so that this will NOT be possible`. You can't prevent this as it would be against language standard - non-const variable can be modified. What are you trying to achieve, there is likely a better way?

Comment: Your bigger problem will be users passing objects which exist on the stack and go out of scope, and there's no (safe) way to check for that, either.

Comment: Try declaring the pointer as `int * const p_abstract_const`. 
This will declate `p_abstract_const` as a pointer to a `const` int.

Comment: @FKaria I think that this will declare a `const` pointer to a non-`const` int. Someone please second this notion

Comment: @FKaria: I think the key here is that the OP wants to prevent a non-const value from being passed in. As far as I understand the C++ standard, you can always "add" more constness in parameters, and there is no way to enforce that something passed into a function is actually `const`. I think my comments above do give some useful advice - basically "make it impossible for the user to access the passed in object in the first place".

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I want the constructor to only accept pointers to `const` objects. The factory function suggested my @MatsPetersson sounds promising. Would like something simpler if possible though.

Comment: Well, the simpler solution is to just trust the caller. I mean it's not like you can't mess up other bits of code in for example STL (try writing with `ostream::write()` and at the same time modify the data being written in a second thread - it will probably mess up your data very badly. And if you use asio, you can mess with the input/output buffers of the read/write functions... No protection there. If someone REALLY wants to do things wrong, there probably is a not so difficult way to do it.

Comment: If you write code for idiots, only idiots will use your code.

Comment: Either `std::move` the object or make a copy. There's no guarantee your caller will play nice with your code, and this code is rife with the potential for bugs. If you take an object or a pointer, either move in a copy or make a copy explicitly.

Comment: Well, documentation it is then

Answer (score 0):

You can make your non-const int* constructor private without providing an implementation:

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        const int * p_abstract_const;   
        //int my application this is a pointer to abstract object
        Foo(int * p_new_concrete_const);

    public:
        Foo(const int * p_new_concrete_const)
        {
            p_abstract_const  = p_new_concrete_const;
        }
        void printX()
        {
            std::cout << *p_abstract_const << std::endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    int concrete_nonconst = 666;
    Foo foo(&concrete_nonconst);    // This won't compile
    const int concrete_const(1);
    Foo foo(&concrete_const);       // But this will
    foo.printX();


    concrete_nonconst=999;          // so that this will NOT be possible
    foo.printX();
}
```